# Find a "matching end node" in directed acyclic graph (DAG)

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

[image]

I'm attempting to introduce the concept of loops to our "node editing tool", which allows a user to define code as a DAG. However I'm facing difficulty resolving some particular values.

**Front-end**

Currently, in order to create a "loop" construct, you would create a "loop start" node (this is just a label for this node, E.G in the diagram `1` is such as a node). Loop start node's have an interface whereby they accepts an array, and will then iterate each item X times.

You can then add X amount of nodes to the output of `1` (that may themselves also be loops, which may recieve data from a "parent" loop). Eventually you will connect these nodes back into a "loop end" node (E.G `F`).

**Back-end**

Whilst we have created a bunch of node's with "loop end" and "loop start" label's on the front-end, at no point have I actually explictly "connected" `1` and `F`. At the point of "running" the graph, we need a way to progrmatically determine each loop start/end.

For example, I can see the user has created the following loops in the diagram, but need a way to progmatically resolve this -

- `1` > `F`
- `2` > `E`
- `3` > `C`
- `6` > `D`

**Solution**

I have tried a bunch of ways. The most recent approach was:

```
   run a DFS, from loop start
      if loopStartPassed = 0
         return from DFS, potential loop end found

      if node is "loop start"
         loopStartPassed++
      if node is "loop end"
         loopStartPassed--

      if (adjacent nodes)
         continue DFS
```

Basically run a DFS from "loop start", if you go past any other "loop starts" for a given branch, increment variable `startCount` by 1, or decrement for "loop end".

If your `startCount` is zero and you reach a "loop end", this is potentially a loop end.

I say "potentially", as these "orphan" connections we'd like to allow (E.G `N2` > `N5`, or `N2` > `N7`) will throw off this count. If I follow the above logic to try and calculate the loop end for `1` (which should be `F`), and travel `1 > N2 > N7` then `startCount` would remain zero, and I would take `C` as my correct "loop end" (which is incorrect)

I attempted to "fix" this problem, by keeping track of "all potential loop ends" (I.E whilst `1 > N2 > N7` would report the wrong loop end, `1 > N1 > 2 > E > F` would not), however could not find a clean way to determine which loop ends were valid/invalid.

Ultimately I think the way to solve this problem of determining loop end/start, is to perhaps first remove orphans (`N2 > N7`, `N2 > N5`) from the adjacency list (I believe they are making it hard/impossible to accurately tell where you are within loops), but I'm struggling on how to achieve this. Any ideas on how to solve this, or other potential solutions on determining start/end (if it's indeed possible) would be much appreciated.

Comment: How does the code determine that a node is a "loop end" or a "loop start" or neither?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to solve. The "UI" allows you to link a "loop start" to a "loop end" node, however the frontend doesn't currently enforce any rules on the X node's that may sit between these (E.G between 1 and F).

I'm after a way to programmatically determine the correct loop end on the back end (I.E I only know of the loop start "1", how can I determine "F" is the correct end in the example given.

Comment: You will have to specify exactly what makes a node a "loop end".  First, it must be reachable from the loop start, but you will have to provide more than that to narrow it down.

Comment: A "Loop end" is simply a node the user added to the graph called that, containing one input (the results of the contents of the loop operation), and an output. It becomes a "loop" when a "loop start" (`1`) is joined to a loop end (`F`), however there may be a lunch of nodes in between that point.

finding a loop end, given a "loop start" was trivial before we allowed nested children, and now "orphans". However I'm not unsure whether it's possible with these new concepts as I (hopefully understandably) explained in the original post.

Comment: So loop starts and ends are labelled as such.  So what is the problem?  Do a breadth first search from the loop start until you find a reachable loop end.

Comment: There is no such labelling in the real world. If you look at the example, you will see the (manual) labels "1" and "F". In the real world, someone adds a "loop start" ("1"), then adds all the nodes between them, and I now need a way to programmatically resolve "F" as the "loop end" for "1". This is difficult for me due to all the other loop end/starts en route (children loops), and nodes which provide data to those children loops.

Comment: You seem confused! You wrote: "A "Loop end" is simply a node the user added to the graph called that"  then you write "There is no such labelling"  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not explaining this clearly. 

The frontend has a node called "Loop start", and "Loop end" (this is their labels). On the "loop start" node you can attach 1 or more additional nodes / loops (as can be seen in the photo), before eventually connecting it back to the loop end (which we'll call "F" here, but this ISN'T explicit it's the correct loop end).

Now at run time I need to work out the correct start/ends for any loop in the graph. whilst it's clear by looking in the that UI "F" is the correct "loop end" for "1", I need to work this out programmatically.

Comment: "a node called "Loop start", and "Loop end" (this is their labels)."  AND ""There is no such labelling"  I give up.

Comment: I appreciate you're trying to help, apologies if my responses are confusing, let me try one last time. The "problem" is there are 2 node's which are labelled (doesn't matter what they are called, "loop start" and "loop end", "x" and "y" whatever), I need an algorithm to determine these node pairs (I.E "1" and "F") given there may be other nodes between them. 

When I said "there is no such labelling", I mean there isn't actually an explicit label to say "Loop start" belongs to "Loop end", perhaps a the term "there is no rule" would be better here apologies.

Comment: A "label" and a "rule" are completely different things.  If you use the same name for different things, you create confusion.  I suggest you edit your answer to sort this out.

Comment: I have re-worded my original question, hopefully it clears any confusion.